# Azure WVD Rest API Auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, wvd

I have a aspnetcore app that I'm writing and would like to be able to manage WVD resources. The problem I'm having is that the Bearer token I'm getting from Msal is giving me a 401 when I try to

```
GET https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/api/feeddiscovery/webfeeddiscovery.aspx
```

I thought maybe I needed to add an API permission to my app in azure, but I've already added:

```
https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
```

And I cant seem to locate anything that suggests it might work for WVD.

Maybe I'm way off track though.

I've tried looking at the source:

https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates/tree/master/wvd-templates/wvd-management-ux/deploy

But its been compiled and minified, so thats proving to be difficult.

Any help getting a valid token to call the WVD Rest API would be greatly appreciated.

Getting the token:

Full Code (minus the Microsoft.Identity.Web stuff)

```
var token = await TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(new[] { "https://mrs-Prod.ame.gbl/mrs-RDInfra-prod/user_impersonation" });
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $"{token}");
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/hubdiscovery/eventhubdiscovery.aspx");
            result = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/feeddiscovery/webfeeddiscovery.aspx");
```

This method is from the [Microsoft.Identity.Web project.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web)

Comment: Just an update, Microsoft.Identity.Web is now a NuGet package. We encourage its usage to keep your library updated and with bug fixed. [Microsoft.Identity.Web wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg I just figured it out by comparing the token I got from the msft rdweb application:

From the RDWeb App:
"aud": "https://mrs-prod.ame.gbl/mrs-RDInfra-prod",

From my App:
"aud": "https://mrs-Prod.ame.gbl/mrs-RDInfra-prod",

....
Yes I was using an uppercase P in - mrs-Prod. And the msft app was using a lowercase p in mrs-prod.

I'm flabbergasted, angry and excited all at the same time.

For the record I copied my value directly from Azure in my apps api permissions screen.

Answer (score 1):

The `https://management.azure.com` is for `Azure Service Management` API, in your case, it is not correct.

Please navigate to the AD App in the portal -> `API permissions` -> `APIs my organization uses` -> search by `Windows Virtual Desktop`, find it and click.

[image]

If you want the management tool to make Windows Virtual Desktop management calls on behalf of the user who's signed into the tool, choose `Delegated permissions` -> `user_impersonation`, complete the steps like the screenshot. You can also let the user consent the permission by himself without clicking the `Grant admin consent` button, it depends on you.

[image]

Then the permission appears like below.

[image]

For more details, see this [**Tutorial: Deploy a management tool**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/manage-resources-using-ui) and this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/manage-resources-using-ui#provide-consent-for-the-management-tool).

**Update:**

Try to use powershell [`New-RdsRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/new-rdsroleassignment) to add user account as a `RDS Owner` role, make sure you have installed the `Microsoft.RDInfra.RDPowerShell` module first, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows-virtual-desktop/overview).

```
Add-RdsAccount -DeploymentUrl "https://rdbroker.wvd.microsoft.com"
Get-RdsTenant
New-RdsRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "RDS Owner" -SignInName "xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -TenantName "joywvd"
```

---

Then I run the `Get-RdsTenant` command again, and use fiddler to catch the request, get the token, decode in the https://jwt.io/, it appears like below.

[image]

The `aud` and `scp` should be the same as your token, you can also decode your token to check, then I use postman to call the `https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/api/feeddiscovery/webfeeddiscovery.aspx`, it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added that to the app, but I'm still getting a 401 even when I have that scope. When I use the same account to load the rdweb portal everything populates fine, so we know the user is good.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Could you provide the code about getting the token?

Comment: updated the question. I've also looked at the tutorial you linked, but with the code being minified its difficult to follow. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Wjdavis5 I think we don't need the `Constants.ScopeUserRead`, `User.Read` is for Microsoft Graph, just use `(new[] {Constants.WVD })` to have a try.

Comment: I have tried it both with and without that scope and still get a 401. Also I wanted to add that I have tried doing other things, such as listing VMs in my account with this same code (different scope of course) and have that working fine. So I know the code to get a token is correct.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Did you consent the permission?

Comment: hm - If I didnt, wouldnt it prompt me for consent every time I log into the application? I want to say yes but I cant think of a way to verify what consent I've given.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Not every time, just the first time when you login. You can click the Grant admin consent button in the portal to make sure the permission has been consented. Then when the user login, it will not prompt him to consent again.

Comment: either way, I've provided admin consent in the azure portal. will test again when I get home.

Comment: same result, 401 when calling /api/feeddiscovery/webfeeddiscovery.aspx

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Did you add your user account as a `RDS Owner`? You could check my update.

Comment: The user account has all required permissions, we know this b/c the default MSFT RDWebclient page works for us.

Comment: just wanted to say thank you again for working with me on this. I really do appreciate it.